# Windows Experience Index memory subscore goes up with added graphics card

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics

After installing a nvidia graphics card in a pcie slot, the memory subscore jumps from 5.9 to 6.7. Could this have to do with my previous integrated graphics using some memory. I have 4 gb of ram dual channel installed, ddr2 800 mhz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly, integrated graphics cards often share system memory, and you have removed both the use of that memory and the contention of the GPU and CPU using the same memory.

Comment: So does this mean that shared memory (intel integrated) is not preallocated and that it slows down overall memory performance?

Comment: Actually, it is allocated, and unavailable to the OS, but it is still the same physical memory, with two separate systems requesting and writing to it.

Comment: Ah, ok. So the windows experience index calculates that two systems writing and requesting the same memory is slower than if just one does.

Comment: @agovizer I don't think the details of the index calculation are public, but I imagine it just subtracts "a bit", rather than doing anything scientific.